# Socket failed error in SOAP request

Tags: android, android-ksoap2

I'm trying to connect to a server using ksoap in android. I have added ksoap jar file as a library and all ksoap imports are working fine. But i'm getting an error in `HttpTransportSE`.

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(Webservices.WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE, "LoginValidate");
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
envelope.dotNet = true;
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(Webservices.SOAP_ADDRESS);
httpTransport.call(Webservices.SOAP_ACTION + "LoginValidate", envelope);
```

I'm getting error at this line, `httpTransport.call(Webservices.SOAP_ACTION + "LoginValidate", envelope);` as socket exception, socket failed.

Comment: Have you added Internet permission in the manifest?

Comment: @KNeerajLal yes we have added the permission

Answer (score 0):

Socket exception means something wrong with your network.

1.Check if the server you visit is OK.

2.Check if network of your mobile phone is OK.